# How to define GraphQLObjectType for a nested object or list of objects in the same parent object

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql, graphql-js

For my MongoDB object, I have a schema where so many nested data are there.

however I implemented perfectly in GraphQL for the query to get the data, but I am unable to fetch the nested data as I am unable to define the types.

```
fields() {
        return {
            name: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                description: 'Name of the person'
            },
            age: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                description: 'Age'
            },
            documents: { // what to do here
                type: new GraphQLList(),
                description: 'All documents for the person'
            }
       }
}
```

The original data is something like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ae1da5e4f00b5eee4ab84ee"),
    "name" : "Indira Gandhi International Airport",
    "age" : 54,
    "documents" : [
        {
             "doc_name" : "personal card",
             "doc_url" : "http://",
             "status" : true
        },
        {
             "doc_name" : "bank card",
             "doc_url" : "http://",
             "status" : true
        }
     ],
    "latitude" : "",
    "longitude" : "",
    "timezone" : "Asia/kolkata"
    .......
}
```

I am new in graphQL, please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do here is have your documents field be a list of documents. In order to do this, you need to create a "document" `GraphQLObjectType` to pass into `new GraphQLList()` in your documents field. Like so:

```
const DocumentType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'DocumentType',
  fields: {
    doc_name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    doc_url: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    status: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean
  }
});
```

Then once you have that created, either in the same file (or in a different file and imported necessarily) with the right dependencies, you plug it into the code you posted above like so:

```
fields() {
        return {
            name: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                description: 'Name of the person'
            },
            age: {
                type: GraphQLString,
                description: 'Age'
            },
            documents: {
                type: new GraphQLList(DocumentType),
                description: 'All documents for the person'
            }
       }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou @ericAbour , this solution works. But got another issue when the child node is a list of complex object. i.e. if  documents : [  name : "", url : "" , tags : [ "t1", "t2"]];    I implemented your solution, data coming to callback. but it not resolved. still documents showing as null

Comment: You should be able to follow the same pattern for tags that you applied to documents. The `tags` field in the DocumentType should be another `GraphQLList` linking to a `TagType` that you define.

Comment: thank you Eric, everything is fine, it is happening because I had a field name 'type". in mongoose schema it was previously defined as         
      type: String after changing it to type: { type: String}, all working now. BDW could you guide me through the filters, paginations implementation in GraphQL query.

Comment: Happy to hear I was able to help you. Filters and pagination are more than I can explain here. Here are a few references for you: https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/ http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Comment: I really appreciate this. I'd been hunting for an answer for well over an hour and you nailed it!